# What does "ぼうし" mean in "帰り道を照らしたのは 思い出のかげぼうし"

Tags: translation

The words are from the popular song, "Paprika". The sentence, "帰り道を照らしたのは 思い出のかげぼうし" is translated as, "A shadow of memories lights up the way home." I would like to know if this translation is accurate.

Also, I am a bit confused by the use of "ぼうし" since I found that it means "hat"!

Comment: It’s かげぼうし, one word.

Answer (score 2):

[かげぼうし](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%A4%AB%A4%B2%A4%DC%A4%A6%A4%B7) means "silhouette", particularly the silhouette of a person according to this dictionary: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E5%BD%B1%E6%B3%95%E5%B8%AB/m1u/